# Visio VBA Change Picture

Tags: vba, visio

Trying to change the person's picture in a Visio org chart.
I can change it by manually clicking "Change Picture" and browsing, but the ChangePicture Method gives me an error.

```
Sub changeShapePicture(ByRef thisShape As Visio.Shape, filepath as string)

If Dir(filepath) <> "" Then
    Debug.Print "File Exists"
    thisShape.ChangePicture(filepath)
    Else
    Debug.Print "Picture File Doesn't Exist"
End If
```

I get an error of "Inappropriate target object for this action."

The method says it returns the picture height/width ratio as a Double.

Also tried

```
dim myRatio as double
myRatio = thisShape.ChangePicture(fullPicPath)
```

and get the same error.

Trying to record a macro yielded no useful code.

Most of the organization boxes have pictures imported when the org chart is created.  However, because of the odd arrangement of who reports to whom, some boxes need to be added in a secondary operation, and that's what I'm trying to automate.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
Solution to changing the picture within the pre-defined Org Chart shapes is to use an Add On

```
Sub changeShapePicture(ByRef thisShape As Visio.Shape, filePath as string)

dim sendTheseKeys as string

sendTheseKeys = filePath + "{ENTER}"
ActiveWindow.Select thisShape, visDeselectAll + visSelect
Dim adn As Visio.Addon
Set adn = Visio.Addons("OrgC11")
SendKeys sendTheseKeys,False
adn.Run "/cmd=ChangePicture"

end sub
```

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate it and got the same error, but I got it working when I tried changing a shape that was placed by pulling a picture directly from the explorer into visio.

It seems the shape has to be a picture to begin with, to be able exchange it.
Check if the Shape you're trying to replace is a picture (see attached pic).
I don't know what your chart looks like or how it's structure is, but make sure to select the right shape, it may be that the picture is a subshape of a another shape(group).

[image: Sheet.2 is the Firefox Logo]

When digging a bit deeper and trying to find the type of the shape with [`shape.type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.type) we see that the first shape (`sheet.2`) is of [type 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.visshapetypes) (ForeignType) and digging deeper with [`shape.foreigntype`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.foreigntype) that it is a visTypeBitmap Object.
The second shape has type 3 and is a [`visTypeShape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.visshapetypes), a native Visio shape.

Since it looks like the [only viable option](https://www.office-forums.com/threads/visio-vba-to-change-a-shapes-image-is-it-possible.1621787/) is to replace the shape i tried the following:

- Import the picture onto the activePage
- Created a new Stencil
- Drop the Shape into the stencil
- use `shape.ReaplaceShape` to replace the old shape

--> Visio crashes this way, but I'll post my code once I get it working. It's also quite likely that there is an much easier way to this....